# How to apply jQuery databale after refreshing its container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to apply jQuery datatable structure after refreshing it's container div.

I have one div in which I have datatable. For the first visit, it works fine, but on button click event I am refreshing it's parent div. And after that I am expecting datatable structure on table but it's not working.

```
<div id="students">   
    <table id="studTable" class="table fullwidth data">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Name</th>
                <th> DOB</th>
                <th> Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var stud in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@stud.Name</td>
                <td>@stud.DOB</td> 
                <td>@stud.Email</td> 
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am reading data from model in MVC view. For first load it shows jQuery datatable structure. On button click I executes this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".submit").click(function (event) {
        $("#students").load(location.href + " #students");
            $("#studTable").dataTable({
                "bSort": false,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bInfo": true,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        });
    })
</script>
```

This code reloads **students** div but the datatable is not getting apply.
And when I am writing datatable's code inside **setTimeout** function then it loads jQuery datatable correctly.

```
setTimeout(function () {          
        }, 1000);
```

but here I don't want to use this `setTimeout(function(){},1000);`

Is there any solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.load()` function is asynchronous, so effectively you're trying to apply the DataTables plugin *before* the content has finished loading.  Instead of applying the plugin on the next line of code, apply it in the asynchronous callback:

```
$("#students").load(location.href + " #students", function () {
    $("#studTable").dataTable({
        "bSort": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    });
});
```